# Can the noun form of "requirement" be used to refer to the state/quality of being required?

Tags: grammar, nouns

Can requirement be used as a synonym for "necessitude"? I have a sentence that ends with wording similar to the following:

> ...due to its requirement in administrative procedures.

It sounds wrong to me since I am cued to read "its requirement" as "its [thing that is needed]," but is it grammatically incorrect to use it this way?

Edit for clarification: Sorry for the confusion. I am wondering if "requirement" can be used to describe the quality of being needed/required--a synonym for "necessariness" or "necessitude." For instance: "The filing cabinet is indispensable due to its requirement in administrative procedures."

Comment: I agree with the OP here. *Our teacher's requirement in the classroom* doesn't and *can't* refer to the necessity of us having a teacher in the classroom - it can *only* refer to ***something the teacher requires*** in relation to the classroom.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems to me the problem there is teachers can make requirements. Whereas "a gavel's requirement in a courtroom" seems fine, since gavels can't talk. But maybe the OP should expand that sentence -- maybe there's some extra subtlety here.

Comment: I would say a simple plural with _for_ instead of _in_ would be sufficient: _Due to its requirements for administrative procedures._

Comment: I've revised my question for clarity. @JohnLawler - "Its requirement for" isn't exactly what I'm getting at here, since the subject isn't doing the requiring, it is the thing that is required.

Comment: Okay, well I see Google Books has both [*Results of the study indicate that a major impact of TSCA has been due to **its requirement**, in effect since 1979 , **that** firms file notification with the EPA 90 days before the manufacture of any new chemical substance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22due+to+its+requirement+%2C+in+effect+since%22) AND [*Boron is known to be essential to life of higher plants, due to its **requirement in flavonoid synthesis**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22plants%2C+due+to+its+requirement%22). That second construction is pretty common.

Comment: (...but I'd still much prefer *...due to its **being required** in [certain circumstances]*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the thorough responses! I'm not surprised that it's used frequently since there really is no good synonym to use in this type of construction. I checked the OED (just found out my uni has a subscription) and it doesn't list _the fact or state of being required_ as a definition, so I think I'll try rewording it. If it wasn't a formal document I think I'd be more willing to let it slide.

Comment: There are an alleged 200 000+ hits on Google for "its requirement in", which seems to force the 'the necessity for it in', 'obligatoriness' sense: 'Compensatory growth renders Tcf7l1a dispensable for eye formation despite its requirement in eye field specification.' / 'Choline Essentiality and Its Requirement in Diets for Juvenile Parrot Fish' / 'Nevertheless, New York abolished its requirement in 1972.' // There's also the quantitative sense: 'daily vitamin B12 requirement'.

Comment: @garnerstan: I don't understand why you say *there really is no good synonym to use in this type of construction*. Even thoughh I don't like it at all, the usage cited in your question is actually quite common. But if ***you*** don't like it either, you can always follow my suggestion above. Ignoring those people who never learned when to write ***its*** and when to write ***it's***, there's absolutely nothing remotely unusual or tricky about *...due to **its being required** in administrative procedures.* Just use that approach every time.

Comment: (Okay - there's still the stylistic choice about whether to write ***its*** or ***it** being required* there. I only chose the former to show that I ***do*** know whether there should be an apostrophe there or not! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just mean that it makes sense that it is used that way in practice since there is no good alternative way to say "requirededness" (necessitude? vitalness?). I acknowledge that it's used pretty frequently and from a descriptivist point of view I agree it's probably fine and I already mentioned I'd be changing it since this is a formal publication and, like you, I don't like it ;)

Comment: I still don't get you. I don't like ***necessitude*** one little bit, but you can get round that one just the same way: *...due to **its being necessary** in administrative procedures* (or ***it being vital***; I think it's irrelevant whether we make that a "possessive" reference to the required / necessary attribute, or stick with ***it being necessary***. Worth noting the US  Constitution here... *A well regulated Militia [i.e. - **it**] being necessary to the security of a free State...*

Comment: I am agreeing with you and just trying to wrap up the discussion. I meant that there's no one-word synonym that can be used as a replacement. That's all. I am not disagreeing that "its being necessary" also works.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Requirement is used broadly to mean "something that for whatever reason was or needs to be included". I'd say it's often used in place of the more precise words "stipulation" and "necessitude". That sentence about administration reads just fine.

You'll sometimes see stipulation used to explicitly point out that something is an externally imposed rule -- "one stipulation: no beards" means they know you could do the job with a beard, but they won't allow you to. But necessitude is rarely used. We'd instead say "not having a beard is a requirement -- the helmet won't fit properly".

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I agree it's often used as "something that needs to be included," but that isn't the same as the state itself of being included. Necessitude is rarely used because it is not a synonym for what you are describing. You would say "not having a beard is a necessity" but that is not the use of requirement that I am asking about. For instance, under "excitement," Mariam Webster lists the definition "the action of exciting: the state of being excited," but under "requirement" it ONLY defines it as something wanted, needed, or essential to something else.

Comment: @garnerstan Obviously I saw this Q as distinguishing the reason for the requirement, which you say isn't the case. Are you saying it's a matter of past/future tense? As in: a requirement mandates what you will do, but what do you called something already done because of a requirement? I wonder if you could edit your Q to clarify?

Comment: I've edited it for clarification now. What I'm getting at is that the subject itself is the thing being required.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant that *some* "requirements" are in fact ***immutable*** (can't be otherwise, such as it being a requirement of a barber's customers that they not be bald), whereas others are effectively ***arbitrary*** (it being a requirement of the opera house that bald patrons wear wigs or hats to avoid their shiny pates creating discordant sound reflections, because some ultra-fussy audiophiles complained about this). As @garnerstan says, it's just a matter of whether "its requirement" can mean ***the requirement that it be present*** as well as ***the thing that it requires***.